# Python, how to create dir within dir?

Tags: python, directory, path, operating-system, mkdir

I'm trying to create a directory(workdir2) which is in the 'workdir1' directory I made. In this situation, what can I do ?

**input_file: name**

```
input_file.txt
```

**Code:**

```
import os
target_name=os.path.basename(input_file).strip().split('.')[0]
workdir1=os.mkdir(target_name + '_prep')
workdir2=os.mkdir('output_file_prep')
```

**Expected result: made path:**

```
./input_file_prep/output_file_prep/
```

Comment: `os.mkdir(workdir1 + "/" + workdir2)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **mkdirs**

```
import os

input_file = "something.txt".split(".")[0]


def mkdirp(path):
    try:
        os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
        print("Done")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


mkdirp(f'./{input_file}_prep/output_file_prep')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create multiple directory at the same time, you can try this code:

```
import os
os.makedirs(f"{workdir1}/{workdir2}")
```